# How to toggle a feature enable or disable feature in terraform without modifying code

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

In Terraform we need to implement a functionality to toggle the block of terraform code(From enable to disable) and redeploy without manually changing the terraform code using commenting the code lines. What is the best way without manually change the code?

Regards
Flashnightss

We tried to manually change the code for example disabling the feature(e.g storage replication disable from enable) using /* */ comment lines. But thats not the good idea for a novice users. Looking for a programmatically implement this without modifying the code manually.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to introduce a feature flag, i.e., a variable that tells the code if a feature/module/block should be used, or not.

E.g., assuming you have a variable `myfeatureflag` declared in your `terraform.tfvars` and you want optionally use a resource block, you could write

```
resource "myresource" "myresourceid" {
  count = var.myfeatureflag == true ? 1 : 0

  <resource-specific code>
}
```

You could do it similarly for calling complete modules.